# return JSON_OBJECT_T response instead of CLOB in PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to return JSON OBJECT but I have a code which returns CLOB, how can I modify below such that I return the JSON_OBJECT_T response instead of clob . Please help

```
DECLARE
  p_json CLOB;
BEGIN
  SELECT JSON_SERIALIZE(
           JSON_OBJECT(
             KEY 'employees' VALUE JSON_ARRAYAGG(
               JSON_OBJECT(
                 KEY 'empno' VALUE id,
                 KEY 'ename' VALUE name,
                 KEY 'job'   VALUE email_id
               )
               ORDER BY id
             )
           )
           RETURNING CLOB
         ) AS json
  INTO   p_json
  FROM   employee_tbl;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(p_json);
END;
/
```

Output expected:

```
{"employees":[{"empno":1065,"ename":"Abu","job":"email1@example.com"},{"empno":1066,"ename":"Umar","job":"email2@example.com"}]}
```

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE employee_tbl (id, name, email_id) AS
  SELECT 1065, 'Abu',  'email1@example.com' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1066, 'Umar', 'email2@example.com' FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the SQL Function `JSON_OBJECT` returns VARCHAR2, CLOB or BLOB (see [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/JSON_OBJECT.html#GUID-1EF347AE-7FDA-4B41-AFE0-DD5A49E8B370))- (JSON can only be returned as from [version 21](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/JSON_OBJECT.html#GUID-1EF347AE-7FDA-4B41-AFE0-DD5A49E8B370)). Convert the result to a json object using `JSON_OBJECT_T.PARSE`.

```
DECLARE
  l_json_object JSON_OBJECT_T;
  l_json CLOB;
BEGIN
   SELECT
      JSON_OBJECT(
         KEY 'employees' VALUE 
            JSON_ARRAYAGG(
               JSON_OBJECT(KEY 'empno' VALUE id
                           ,KEY 'ename' VALUE name
                           ,KEY 'job' VALUE email_id)
               ORDER BY id) 
            RETURNING CLOB)
     INTO l_json
     FROM employee_tbl;
   -- now convert clob to JSON_OBJECT_T
   l_json_object := JSON_OBJECT_T.PARSE(l_json);
   -- or...this works too
   -- l_json_object := JSON_OBJECT_T(l_json);

   -- check if value is correct
   dbms_output.put_line(l_json_object.to_clob);
END;
/


{"employees":[{"empno":1065,"ename":"Abu","job":"email1@example.com"},{"empno":1066,"ename":"Umar","job":"email2@example.com"}]}


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: From Oracle 21, [`JSON_OBJECT`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/JSON_OBJECT.html#GUID-1EF347AE-7FDA-4B41-AFE0-DD5A49E8B370) can also return a `JSON` data type.

Answer (score 0):

Is it JSON_OBJECT or JSON_OBJECT_T what you need? If JSON_OBJECT then
just remove JSON_SERIALIZE from your query and you'll get a JSON_OBJECT as in output expected.

```sql
/*    S a m p l e    D a t a :
ID    NAME     EMAIL_ID
----  -------  ------------------
1065  Abu      email1@example.com
1066  Umar     email2@example.com  */
```

```sql
  SELECT JSON_OBJECT
           ( KEY 'employees' 
             VALUE JSON_ARRAYAGG
                   ( JSON_OBJECT( KEY 'empno' VALUE id,
                                  KEY 'ename' VALUE name,
                                  KEY 'job'   VALUE email_id
                                )
                    ORDER BY id
                  )
           )
         AS json
  FROM   employee_tbl;
```

```sql
/*      R e s u l t :
JSON
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{"employees":[{"empno":1065,"ename":"Abu","job":"email1@example.com"},{"empno":1066,"ename":"Umar","job":"email2@example.com"}]}    */
```

Comment: This is not what the question was asking. The OP wants a [`JSON_OBJECT_T`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/arpls/json-types.html#GUID-10062646-E36F-48B1-9F24-751B613DFB5A) PL/SQL data type.

Comment: @MT0 There are 2 versions in question 1st: "return JSON OBJECT but ..." and 2nd: "...return the JSON_OBJECT_T..." + output expected... not sure which one is it...

Answer (score 0):

Serialize the JSON to a `CLOB` and then parse the `CLOB` to a `JSON_OBJECT_T` (and then if you want to print it you can convert it back to a `CLOB`):

```sql
DECLARE
  p_json CLOB;
  p_jobj JSON_OBJECT_T;
BEGIN
  SELECT JSON_SERIALIZE(
           JSON_OBJECT(
             KEY 'employees' VALUE JSON_ARRAYAGG(
               JSON_OBJECT(
                 KEY 'empno' VALUE id,
                 KEY 'ename' VALUE name,
                 KEY 'job'   VALUE email_id
                 RETURNING JSON
               )
               ORDER BY id
               RETURNING JSON
             )
             RETURNING JSON
           )
           RETURNING CLOB
         ) AS json
  INTO   p_json
  FROM   employee_tbl;

  p_jobj := JSON_OBJECT_T(p_json);

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(p_jobj.to_clob);
END;
/
```

*Note: If you are using Oracle 12-19 then use `RETURNING CLOB` rather than `RETURNING JSON`.*

or, return a `JSON` data-type from the query:

```sql
DECLARE
  p_json JSON;
  p_jobj JSON_OBJECT_T;
BEGIN
  SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
           KEY 'employees' VALUE JSON_ARRAYAGG(
             JSON_OBJECT(
               KEY 'empno' VALUE id,
               KEY 'ename' VALUE name,
               KEY 'job'   VALUE email_id
               RETURNING JSON
             )
             ORDER BY id
             RETURNING JSON
           )
           RETURNING JSON
         )
  INTO   p_json
  FROM   employee_tbl;

  p_jobj := JSON_OBJECT_T(p_json);

  
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(p_jobj.to_clob);
END;
/
```

Which, for the sample data, both output:

```
{"employees":[{"empno":1065,"ename":"Abu","job":"email1@example.com"},{"empno":1066,"ename":"Umar","job":"email2@example.com"}]}
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/CvcnqWEo)