# JSON_OBJECT_T error - The provided JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) operator generated a result which exceeds the maximum length

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to get the data from the table with below PL/SQL but in my case i have some 30 records and when I fetch I'm getting below error.
I need response in JSON_OBJECT_T format only but I want to avoid this error message.

> 40478. 00000 -  "output value too large (maximum: %s)"
>        *Cause:    The provided JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) operator generated a
>        result which exceeds the maximum length specified in the RETURN
>        clause.
>        *Action:   Increase the maximum size of the data type in the RETURNING clause
>        or use a CLOB or BLOB in the RETURNING clause.

```
DECLARE
  l_json_object JSON_OBJECT_T;
  l_json CLOB;
BEGIN
   SELECT
      JSON_OBJECT(
         KEY 'employees' VALUE 
            JSON_ARRAYAGG(
               JSON_OBJECT(KEY 'empno' VALUE id
                           ,KEY 'ename' VALUE name
                           ,KEY 'job' VALUE email_id)
               ORDER BY id) 
            RETURNING CLOB)
     INTO l_json
     FROM employee_tbl;
   -- now convert clob to JSON_OBJECT_T
   l_json_object := JSON_OBJECT_T.PARSE(l_json);
   -- or...this works too
   -- l_json_object := JSON_OBJECT_T(l_json);

   -- check if value is correct
   dbms_output.put_line(l_json_object.to_clob);
END;
/
```

Output expected:

```
{"employees":[{"empno":1065,"ename":"Abu","job":"email1@example.com"},{"empno":1066,"ename":"Umar","job":"email2@example.com"}]}
```

Table sample:

```
CREATE TABLE employee_tbl (id, name, email_id) AS
  SELECT 1065, 'Abu',  'email1@example.com' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1066, 'Umar', 'email2@example.com' FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the array aggregation to produce a CLOB, as well as the final outer JSON object; so

```
               ORDER BY id)
            RETURNING CLOB)
     INTO l_json
```

becomes

```
               ORDER BY id
               RETURNING CLOB) 
            RETURNING CLOB)
     INTO l_json
```

making that whole query:

```
   SELECT
      JSON_OBJECT(
         KEY 'employees' VALUE 
            JSON_ARRAYAGG(
               JSON_OBJECT(KEY 'empno' VALUE id
                           ,KEY 'ename' VALUE name
                           ,KEY 'job' VALUE email_id)
               ORDER BY id
               RETURNING CLOB) 
            RETURNING CLOB)
     INTO l_json
     FROM employee_tbl;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pT77vCXD) with extended/repeated data to reproduce the initial error, and modified output so it displays part of the CLOB result.

Answer (score 0):

As shown on [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78099977/1509264), if you are using Oracle 21c or later then use `RETURNING JSON`:

```sql
DECLARE
  l_json_object JSON_OBJECT_T;
  l_json JSON;
BEGIN
  SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
           KEY 'employees' VALUE 
             JSON_ARRAYAGG(
               JSON_OBJECT(
                 KEY 'empno' VALUE id
                ,KEY 'ename' VALUE name
                ,KEY 'job' VALUE email_id
                 RETURNING JSON
               )
               ORDER BY id
               RETURNING JSON
             ) 
           RETURNING JSON
         )
  INTO   l_json
  FROM   employee_tbl;

  l_json_object := JSON_OBJECT_T(l_json);

  -- check if value is correct
  dbms_output.put_line(l_json_object.to_clob);
END;
/
```

If you are using earlier versions then use `RETURNING CLOB` rather than `RETURNING JSON`.